# embed php tags to display xml from url

Tags: php

I have been working on this sports website as kind of a learning project.

I have a table laid out in html to organize the xml data

I am using this script to pull live data from a remote server that provides it in xml.

```
<?php
$url = "http://xml.feed.com";
$xmlinfo = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($xmlinfo);
?>
```

This is the first time I have ever use php so any advice/criticism would be greatly appreciated and excepted.

Here is a sample of simpleXML.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(

[params] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [legend] => False
                [catId] => -1
                [sportId] => -1
                [matchId] => -1
                [delta] => 60
                [deltaUtc] => 2014-01-25T00:35
                [utc] => 2014-01-25T01:35
                [includeCent] => False
                [includeFraction] => False
            )

    )

[data] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [s] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 1
                                [n] => American Football
                            )

                        [cat] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1109
                                        [n] => NFL Pro Bowl
                                    )

                                [m] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 1015211
                                                [n] => Team Rice v Team Sanders
                                                [mid] => 573422
                                                [rot] => 495
                                                [dt] => 2014-01-27T00:30
                                            )

                                        [t] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 1
                                                                [n] => Single Match
                                                            )

                                                        [l] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => Team Rice
                                                                [1] => Team Sanders
                                                            )
```

I have been trying to figure out how to display this xml data using php tags embedded in the html code..

So I have 2 questions.

1. How would these tags be written?
2. And, Am I heading in the right direction as far as my approach using php embedded in html?

Thanks much in advance! And I hope I was clear enough...

Comment: what tags? html is a markup language. You're basically asking "using words, how do I write a novel?" As for php-in-html... PHP is templating engine. It's supposed to produce html and/or be embedded in html...

Comment: I used the wrong term "tags".